# Using a class object as an argument

Tags: python

I'm quite confused about how to approach this. I want to add the `x` and `y` coordinates in the `Car` class like

```
class Car:
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
```

and then I need to implement these arguments into the keys in the dict `_cars`, but since the keys which are 'id_', are in strings, I can't do something like:

```
temp = Car(0,0)
self._cars[temp] = fuel
```

How can I approach this?

```
class SuperDuperManager:
    """A class responsible for keeping track of all cars in the system.

    === Private Attributes ===
    @type _cars: dict[str, Car]
        A map of unique string identifiers to the corresponding Car.
        For example, _cars['a01'] would be a Car object corresponding to
        the id 'a01'.
    """
    def __init__(self):
        """Initialize a new SuperDuperManager.

        There are no cars in the system when first created.

        @type self: SuperDuperManager
        @rtype: None
        """
        self._cars = {}

    def add_car(self, id_, fuel):
        """Add a new car to the system.

        The new car is identified by the string <id_>, and has initial amount
        of fuel <fuel>.

        Do nothing if there is already a car with the given id.

        @type self: SuperDuperManager
        @type id_: str
        @type fuel: int
        @rtype: None
        """
        # Check to make sure the identifier isn't already used.
        if id_ not in self._cars:
            # TODO: Add the new car.
            if self._cars[id_] = fuel

    def move_car(self, id_, new_x, new_y):
        """Move the car with the given id.

        The car called <id_> should be moved to position (<new_x>, <new_y>).
        Do nothing if there is no car with the given id,
        or if the corresponding car does not have enough fuel.

        @type self: SuperDuperManager
        @type id_: str
        @type new_x: int
        @type new_y: int
        @rtype: None
        """
        if id_ in self._cars:
            # TODO: Move the car with id <id_>.
            if self._cars[id_] >= (new_x + new_y):
                    remaining_fuel = self._cars[id] - (new_x + new_y)
                    self._cars[id_] = Car(new_x, new_y, remaining_fuel)

    def get_car_position(self, id_):
        """Return the position of the car with the given id.

        Return a tuple of the (x, y) position of the car with id <id_>.
        Return None if there is no car with the given id.

        @type self: SuperDuperManager
        @type id_: str
        @rtype: (int, int) | None
        """
        if id_ in self._cars:
            # TODO: Get the position of the car with id <id_>.
            return (self._cars[id_].x, self._cars[id_].y)

    def get_car_fuel(self, id_):
        """Return the amount of fuel of the car with the given id.

        Return None if there is no car with the given id.

        @type self: SuperDuperManager
        @type id_: str
        @rtype: int | None
        """
        if id_ in self._cars:
            # TODO: Get the amount of fuel of the car with id <id_>.
            return (self._cars[id_].fuel)

    def dispatch(self, x, y):
        """Move a car to the given location.

        Choose a car to move based on the following criteria:
        (1) Only consider cars that *can* move to the location.
            (Ignore ones that don't have enough fuel.)
        (2) After (1), choose the car that would move the *least* distance to
            get to the location.
        (3) If there is a tie in (2), pick the car whose id comes first
            alphabetically. Use < to compare the strings.
        (4) If no cars can move to the given location, do nothing.

        @type self: SuperDuperManager
        @type x: int
        @type y: int
        @rtype: None
        """
        # TODO: Implement this method!
        pass

class Car:
    """A car in the Super system.
    """
    def __init__(self, x, y, fuel):
            self.x = x
            self.y = y
            self.fuel = fuel
```

Comment: What if you were to let 'fuel' be another attribute of your Car class, so that Car contains everything relating to a particular car (location and fuel)? Then the self._cars dict would have the _id strings as the dict's keys, and the corresponding instances of the Car class as the values.

Comment: @ehaymore thanks for the reply. The code above is fixed, so if i could, i would move both fuel and id into my car class but i cant. and even if i were to have fuel in my car class, wouldnt that be  bad style because I have fuel in the superdupermanager class as well?

Comment: OK, got it. What about still using the id_ string as the keys, but having the value be a 2-element list containing the Car instance and the fuel?

Comment: u mean something like
newcar = Car()
self._cars[id_] = ((newcar.x, newcar.y), fuel)?

i feel like that would complicate this so much

Comment: Having `fuel` be related to the Car isn't necessarily bad style - it's not uncommon for "container" objects like `SuperDuperManager` to expose some attributes that are proxied to the things they contain, especially if those things (in this case, the Cars) aren't exposed directly. It is already exposing the x,y position of each Car; making fuel an additional attribute does make the most sense.

Comment: @lvc your right. i've added fuel and x and y coordinates to my car class. and i have edited the orginal post as so. However, im stuck at the get_car_position

Comment: You can use _id to retrieve the right Car instance from the self._cars dict, and then get x and y from the Car instance you just found.

Comment: @ehaymore could you give me a hint? i lost you there :( The dict is just a ('id_', fuel). how can i retrieve the right Car instance from a string value and get the x,y from it?

Comment: Take a look at the documentation given for self._cars: "For example, _cars['a01'] would be a Car object corresponding to the id 'a01'." You need to have the dict keep track of Cars, not fuel. And now that you have fuel inside the Car class, you can keep track of everything you need within Car.

Comment: @ehaymore that def does help but im confused on how to implement that now ;/ I have edited to update on what i have

Comment: Great! You're welcome.

Comment: @ehaymore dont goo i might still need you! trying to figure out few more problems on my own before I get stuck again :(

Comment: @ehaymore I have edited the def get_car_fuel. However when i do 

user = SuperDuperManager()
User.add_car('lexus',5)
User.get_car_fuel('lexus')

it doesnt seem to return 5

Comment: get_car_fuel() and the Car class look right. The problem must be in how the car is being set up in add_car(). Is your add_car() code above up to date? It's not actually adding anything to self._cars. You need to create a new Car in add_car() and add it to self._cars.

Comment: @ehaymore nvm thanks so much for the help. the key to solving this was in the docstring all along. i should read them more carefully instead of ignoring them thank you!